# Problem with TCA columns with foreign table after migrating from LTS 7 to LTS 8

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, typo3-tca

I'm working in a old extension.

After migrating from LTS 7, I have "invalid values (1)" in each of my TCA select types, but the correct value is checked in the list.

All upgrade wizards are OK and Database compare too.

I am using a TCA column with foreign table like this:

```php
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tx_myextension_model'] = array(
    'columns' => array(
        'diploma_type' => array(
            'exclude' => 1,
            'config' => array(
                'type' => 'select',
                'renderType' => 'selectSingle',
                'MM' => 'sys_category_record_mm',
                'MM_match_fields' => array(
                    'fieldname' => 'diploma_type',
                    'tablenames' => 'tx_extension_name',
                ),
                'MM_opposite_field' => 'items',
                'foreign_table' => 'sys_category',
                'foreign_table_where' => ' AND (sys_category.sys_language_uid = 0 OR sys_category.l10n_parent = 0) AND pid = 35 ORDER BY title',
                'size' => 10,
                'autoSizeMax' => 20,
                'minitems' => 0,
                'maxitems' => 20,
                'behaviour' => array(
                    'allowLanguageSynchronization' => true,
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

In the table `tx_myextension_model.diploma_type` TYPO3 save the value `1` and in `sys_category_record_mm` the correct value.

Any thoughts?

Comment: not sure, but try to set `"default" => 0,`

Comment: thanks but same result.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with sys_categories, but maybe using the documented method of creating a categorizable table can help... Or at least show the required settings/differences of the TCA. https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/8.7/en-us/ApiOverview/Categories/Index.html#making-a-table-categorizable

Comment: Thanks for the link. Same behaviour with that example. I switched my selectSingle to selectTree.